# Progressbar in RecyclerView keeps showing on top

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a recyclerview , in that recyclerview i have list of cardview ..the content is static, it'll not change or something. when i drag the list to the top, a progressbar appears and stays there.

How to solve that problem. I've searched on internet, without finding something related. Thanks for the answer!

Photo from the emulator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9XMC.png (notice the progressbar loading in the middle)

**RVAdapter.java**

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView personName;
        TextView personAge;
        ImageView personPhoto;
        Button personbutton;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personAge = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_age);
            personPhoto = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
            personbutton=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgbuttondownload);

        }
    }

    List<Person> persons;

    RVAdapter(List<Person> persons){
        this.persons = persons;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int i) {
        personViewHolder.personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
        personViewHolder.personPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context=v.getContext();
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                switch (i){
                    case 0:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Main4Activity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Main4Activity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Main4Activity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent =  new Intent(context, Main4Activity.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        personViewHolder.personbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Person person = persons.get(i);
                Context context=v.getContext();
                String url = person.url;

                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.setDescription(person.title);
                request.setTitle(person.title);

                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(
                        DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "file"+person.title+".mp4");
                manager.enqueue(request);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        rv=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rv);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        }, REQUEST_CODE);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        initializeData();
        initializeAdapter();
}

  private void initializeData(){
        persons = new ArrayList<>();
        persons.add(new Person("How to perform a staphylectomy | Surgical correction of RLN", "10:07", R.drawable.chirurgie,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1mxYNzdeCtp7mP5Jv0gqESTgIFa9pGhF1","YESddddd"));
        persons.add(new Person("How to perfom a clinical examination", "07:03", R.drawable.chirurgie,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1mxYNzdeCtp7mP5Jv0gqESTgIFa9pGhF1","gvjhkllklkj2bb"));
        persons.add(new Person("How to perform a radiographic examination", "03:50", R.drawable.chirurgie,"https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1mxYNzdeCtp7mP5Jv0gqESTgIFa9pGhF1","nadaaa"));


    }

    private void initializeAdapter(){
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(persons);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

activity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <include layout="@layout/app_bar_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:id="@+id/nv3"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"

        >

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

App_bar_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/redcolor"
        android:layout_height="192dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="30dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="2dp"
            app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedAppBar"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedAppBar"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagetoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/rv"
        >

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: The question is too narrow to understand. I mean, explain in details on how are you showing the loading indicator with some example codes. Then only members can help.

Comment: as you can see in the emulator ..when i drag the list up(to the top), like i'm trying to synchronize or actualize the list ..a loading cursor show up and it never stop spining ..

Comment: Please show your adapter-code and the code where you update when you drag.

Comment: @hamena314 please check the edited post

Comment: @Rajarshi i've provide the code if you're interested!

Comment: Where is the loading icon/progress bar code that actually is showing the loading icon?

Comment: i Don't have any icon/progress bar ..is not that a feature of recyclerview

Comment: @Zouhair Yes, that's true, and it can be implemented by the coder only, that's why I'm asking you for the same. If you are still unsure and your project is not so personal then upload it to github and post the link here so that other can review it.

Comment: Post your xml for the activity and the recyclerview item

Comment: @Rajarshi yeah i don't mind, would you give me your email ..thanks for the interest in helping

Comment: @mTak  i did it ..please see the updated post

Comment: @Rajarshi thanks dude ..i got the solution from mTak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a SwipeRefreshLayout. 
Find it by `findViewById` and then call

```
swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
swipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: actually setEnabled alone will do the job ..but glad you pointed it out! thanks again dude